# WordPress migration is redirecting me to do a new installation of WordPress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migrate

I thought I followed the steps to migrate my WordPress site over to a new host correctly but when I navigate to the new site I am getting redirected to the WordPress installation page. Here was my process:

- ZIP'ed up all of the files of my old WordPress site
- Exported the MySQL database
- Uploaded and unzipped the files on the new host
- Imported the MySQL database on the new host
- Changed the database connection information in the wp-config.php
- Changed the siteurl and home in the database options table

Obviously I am missing something but it is not jumping out at me as to where or what I have overlooked.

Comment: You should get Velvet Blue's URL switcher to go though the DB and update URL's. But as it's a wordpress plugin you need a working site.  I seen this before, but I can't recall what was wrong.  I think it was something weird like file permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance you have done enough it probably should load.  Looks like the wp-config is invalid or missing if it's wanting to do a new installation from scratch.  Check file permissions and server logs.  Use [wp cli](https://wp-cli.org/) to try and verify parts.  E.g. `wp db cli` will try and connnect to the DB, so that should fail if the DB connection isn't right (quite a likely cause) and `wp shell` will give you a PHP console with WP laoded - I find this often prints out useful debugging info if it fails.

However, am I right in deducing from your *"Changed the siteurl and home in the database options table"* that you migrated not only to a new *host*, but a different *domain* as well?  In that case you need to change much more in the DB than just those two settings.  WP stores all internal links as absolute URLs for example.  I would again use wp-cli.  The following command is fairly powerful and wide-ranging, so think through your values, but I use it for this kind of migration:

```
wp search-replace 'old.domain.name' 'shiny.new.domain.name' --all-tables
```

If it's a multi-site installation, there's a constant in wp-config.php for the default domain that needs updating too

Comment: That wp cli utility helped me figure out that I had my table prefix wrong. Now I get a blank page instead of redirected to the new installation page.

Comment: Probably the links.  Try the search-replace

Comment: I think I have it worked out now. The main thing was the table prefix being incorrect but the wp cli made it obvious. Very handy tool!